# SharkORM - How to parse results of Joins

Tags: ios, objective-c, dbaccess

I am trying to use SharkORM to fetch relationships across my objects. I am familiar with the [joinTo syntax](https://github.com/sharksync/sharkorm#joins) defined in SharkORM's documentation, but I am not sure how to use the resulting joinedResults object to get the related objects I need.

```
[[Person query] joinTo:[Department class] leftParameter:@"department" targetParameter:@"Id"]
```

outputs

```
{
    "Department.Id" = 61;
    "Department.location" = 35;
    "Department.name" = Development;
}
```

into the Person.joinedResults field, but how do I take those results and get a Department object back. I've tried making a call to  person.department after the joinTo, but it seems to make a second query to the database as if I hadn't used joinTo at all.

Am I really expected to parse the dictionary results of person.joinedResults into a Department object manually? That is very cumbersome, especially when you start joining more than one relationship.

I feel as if I am missing some obvious way to use the results of the joinTo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join functionality is in addition to relationships.  So you can reference unrelated (or related) tables in a query, but then objects you get back can only ever be physically structured as per your original class, and are defined from the data and not from your query.

So, in a nut shell;  joinTo: will enable you to reference remote or unrelated objects in your query for selection.

But to traverse object relationships you would use the properties.

```
Person* p = GetFirstPerson()
// reference/traverse the object to look at relationships (1:1)
p.department
```

or

```
p.department.location
```

So I guess what i'm saying is, even though it is SQL like syntax, you can only ever end up with rigidly defined classes in a fixed structure as a result unless using other interfaces such as sum, distinct etc..

Comment: Okay, is there a way to do eager loading then? If I query a list of Persons, do I have to make a separate database call to get the Department relationship of every object?

Comment: Well, you don't have too in that the ORM know that your department property if set, relates to a Department record, and will lazily load the first time and then cache the result for future access.  Because it is a PK lookup 1:1, the delay is actually fairly minimal, the bulk of the time being the creation of the class and it's rehydration.  When testing the original product (DBAccess) many years ago we found a heavy query, inflating all branches with full objects was common on heavy architecture, but highly counter productive on little ARM devices with limited memory but fast flash storage.

Comment: So the time taken to do the query was one of the smallest parts, and everything after the query was where the time was spent.  Therefore, lazily loading the relationship upon access was a design decision made to be slightly faster in several scenarios, but slower if you happen to touch every single related object in sequence.  But it used far more memory, and often resulted in a spike which was unnecessary at the time.

Comment: Understood. We'll have to figure out a better way to load the results. Might need to fall back to raw sql for this one section of the code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, you do kind of get the raw values, in your joined values dictionary?  So it's already done?

Comment: I mean, you have the column values, so you could create a sterilised version of the Department class, and return it via a method on the original class.  You would not be able to commit that object back in, but it would achieve what you wanted.